# Hide shipping option if another available

Tags: checkout, shipping, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

I have a freeshipping and another (same shipping but with price).

THe set up is that when the cart is more than 35€ the freeshipping is applied.

But the problem is that another shipping is also displayed.

I want to hide it if the free shipping is available.

I found one short tutorial witch suggested to include this code before `dt` in `available.phtml` this code:

```
    <?php 
if ( array_key_exists('freeshipping_freeshipping', $_shippingRateGroups)){
    unset($_shippingRateGroups["flatrate_flatrate"]);
}
?>
```

But it doesn't work for me... I don't know why.

I'm on Magento 1.9,

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you put in the table rate extension you will get far more flexibility and not have to change phtml files. I think if you can do something using whats there it is always preferable.

So In tablerates you would have 2 rows:

1) rate upto 35€
2) free shipping rate over

Very simple spreadsheet.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping

If you need multiple table rates then MatrixRates is a good option - and is free.

Comment: Yes I know about this, but the issue is, that I have different shipping methods. Example: Simple shipping I use table rates based on price as you say. But this shipping method is NOT deliver to clients home, but the nearest post office. And I have another one witch deliver's the items to the client's home. I hope I'm explaining myself.

Comment: So you need 2 shipping methods?  If so then use Matrixrates, you can put in multiple shipping methods. E.g. offer Ground and 2nd Day as options.

Comment: Hey, I've decided to go with Table Rates, I will see into the MatrixRates, maybe it will solve my problem. I need to test it first. Thanks. Now I'm trying to apply the defautl shipping method in cart, any ideas? I tryed using this extension:http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/auto-shipping-pro.html but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't have to use 2 shipping methods... on my Store I do it like this:

- I have one shipping method with the specified cost
- I have created a Shopping Cart Rule: `Backedn -> Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules` that does the math

In the Rule Conditions, Specify that the total should be greater than or equal to 35, and in the Actions just specify "Free Shipping"

Now the cost of the shipping will be reduced to 0 when the cart's total is greater than 35€.